# How To Assign Slices While Iterating Over a Vec in Rust without copying?

Tags: csv, rust, slice, allocation, text-parsing

I am trying to efficiently parse CSV files line by line without unnecessary memory allocation.

Since we can't index into strings in Rust, my idea was to create a struct for each line that has an owned `Vec<char>` of the line characters and several `&[char]` slices representing the locations in that `Vec` of the fields that will require further processing.

I am supporting English only, so there's no need for Unicode graphemes.

I grab each line from the `BufReader`, collect it into my `Vec<char>` and then iterate over the characters to notice the correct offsets for each field slice:

```
let mut r_line: String;
let mut char_count: usize;
let mut comma_count: usize;
let mut payload_start: usize;
for stored in &ms7_files {
    let reader = BufReader::new(File::open(&stored.as_path()).unwrap());
    for line in reader.lines() {
        r_line = line.unwrap().to_string();
        let r_chars: Vec<char> = r_line.chars().collect();
        char_count = 0;
        comma_count = 0;
        payload_start = 0;
        for chara in r_chars {
            char_count += 1;
            if chara == ',' {
                comma_count += 1;
                if comma_count == 1 {
                    let r_itemid = &r_chars[0..char_count - 1];
                    payload_start = char_count + 1;
                } else if comma_count == 2 {
                    let r_date = &r_chars[payload_start..char_count - 1];
                    let r_payload = & r_chars[payload_start..r_line.len() - 1];
                }
            }
        }
        // Code omitted here to initialize a struct described in my
        // text above and add it to a Vec for later processing
    }
}
```

All goes swimmingly until the code inside `if` tests on `comma_count` where I attempt to create char slices into the `Vec`.  When I attempt to compile, I get the dreaded:

```
proc_sales.rs:87:23: 87:30 error: use of moved value: `r_chars` [E0382]
proc_sales.rs:87                        let r_itemid = &r_chars[0..char_count - 1];
                                                        ^~~~~~
proc_sales.rs:87:23: 87:30 help: run `rustc --explain E0382` to see a detailed explanation
proc_sales.rs:82:17: 82:24 note: `r_chars` moved here because it has type `collections::vec::Vec<char>`, which is non-copyable
proc_sales.rs:82            for chara in r_chars {
                                     ^~~~~~~
```

for each of the attempts to create a slice. I can basically understand why the compiler is complaining. What I'm trying to figure out is a better strategy to collect and process this data without resorting to a lot of copying and cloning. Heck, if I could leave the original `String` (for each file line) owned by the `BufReader` and just hold on to slices into that, I would!

Feel free to comment on fixing up the above code as well as suggestions for alternative approaches to this problem that limit unnecessary copying.

Comment: I can't test because I am on the train.. but I am willing to bet its because your for loop is actually syntactic sugar for `r_chars.into_iter()`.. which will take ownership. If you instead explicitly use `for chara in r_chars.iter()`.. then it will return references.

Comment: **Definitely** use the [csv crate](https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv). "At the lowest level, the parser can decode CSV at about 200 MB/sec." And that entails zero allocations.

Comment: *Since we can't index into strings in Rust,* — sure you can. You just have to use byte offsets that lie on UTF-8 character boundaries. There are even iterators like [`char_indices`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices).

Comment: Thanks for the comments and insight.  @Shepmaster , the meta articles I found that explained in-line code didn't seem to work for me -- when I futzed with the pre and code tags, the preview only showed me the Vec portion and not the rest.  What is the correct markup that you used?

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for the link to char_indexes.  I was going by the official Rust documentation on strings which states: "Because strings are valid UTF-8, strings do not support indexing" and gives an example of how attempting to do so witth square-brackets syntax fails.   I guess the doc could use some clarifying!
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html#indexing

Comment: *What is the correct markup that you used?* you can review the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37290216/revisions) and also [edit] the post again to see the current markdown (which I didn't fix, so that credit goes elsewhere ^_^). *strings do not support indexing* — ah, this is a nuanced point that I might have misrepresented. You can't do `some_string[2]`, but you *can* do `some_string[2..]` to get a substring (as long as `2` is a valid UTF-8 boundary). This means you can get a single UTF-8 character as a substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`BufReader::lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) returns a iterator that produces `Result<String>` items. When `unwrap` is called on such a item it will always allocates a new `String` (note that in `line.unwrap().to_string()`,  `to_string()` is redundant).

If you want to minimize allocations, you can use [`BufReader::read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line).

To split the fields of a CSV line you can use [`str::split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.split).

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut line = String::new();
    let ms7_files = ["file1.cvs", "file2.cvs"];
    for stored in &ms7_files {
        let mut reader = BufReader::new(File::open(stored).unwrap());
        while reader.read_line(&mut line).unwrap() > 0 {
            // creates a scope to the iterator, so we can call line.clear()
            {
                // does not allocate
                let mut it = line.split(',');
                // item_id, date and payload are string slices, that is &str
                let item_id = it.next().expect("no item_id fied");
                let date = it.next().expect("no date field");
                let payload = it.next().expect("no payload field");
                // process fields
            }
            // sets len of line to 0, but does not deallocate
            line.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to take a look at [various](https://crates.io/search?q=csv) crates to work with CSV files.

Comment: Hey, I really like this solution.  Clearing an already-allocated string fits perfectly into the intent of my question.  I knew of str::split, but was rolling my own just to experiment with low-level processing.  For production, I'm sure I'll use split.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, as @Simon Whitehead answered, ownership of `r_chars` has already been transferred to build the `IntoIterator`, thus you cannot use this.

Modifying your code using

```
for chara in &r_chars
// equivalent to
// for chara in r_chars.iter()
```

AND copying `*chara` whenever you want (cheap) will probably fix it.

For @malbarbo's answer, I would advise against using `BufReader::lines` if your csv contains text columns (which can itself contain line break).

Looking at [crates.io](https://crates.io/search?q=csv) I instead advise using either the battle tested [csv](https://crates.io/crates/csv) or if you need slightly more performance but are ready for much less tested one [quick-csv](https://crates.io/crates/quick-csv).

Comment: Thanks for code that fixes my original design flaw. I have control over the CSV layout, which doesn't include line breaks per record, so I'm going to pursue the solution supplied by @malbarbo